# How to get sentence simplification by StanfordCoreNLP/tregex in python

Tags: python-2.7, stanford-nlp

```
i/p: "Sentence - To give another example, I did study from IIT college. I am bearing black shirt"
o/p: "Sentence - I did study from IIT college."
```

Note: Here i/p: will be dynamic. And o/p should be simplified meaningful sentence.

Comment: Hi @Elazar, Any idea about sentence simplification, Your help will appreciable.

Comment: I have little experience with NLP. Are you sure stanford-nlp supports this kind of service?

Comment: Hi @Elazar, Actually my senior given me hint that try with tregex. i am able to do by making the rules like (VP < (VBD $ PP $ SBAR)). but that is working for particular sentence.  I need to make comman function  so that it should work for any dynamic sentence.